# send name of structure parameter as argument

Tags: c, structure

Does somebody know how to do send name of structure parameter as argument? I have code like this:

```
typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
  double dis;
} Point;

void bucketSort (Point * points, name /*name of parameter*/)
{
  printf("%lf",points.name);
}
```

And, for example, call of function as i see it:

```
bucketSort(point1,"dis");
```

Comment: Rather use a comparator function.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can't send variable name as parameter But. You can check it like below

```
typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
  double dis;
} Point;

void bucketSort (Point * points,char *name /*name of parameter*/)
{
   if(name[0] == 'd' ) printf("%lf",points.dis);
   else if(name[0] == 'x') printf("%lf",points.x);
   else if(name[0] == 'y') printf("%lf",points.y);

}
```

Comment: thank you for answering! It's a pity we can't do that way, but i glad it's so easy to solve by other the other one

Comment: @hououinkyouma you can accept it as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `enum` and store all possible names. Then you can use this `enum` as the parameter to your function.

```
typedef enum {
    ENUM_X = 0,
    ENUM_Y = 1,
    ENUM_DIS = 2
} STRCT_PARAM_NAME;

typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
  double dis;
} Point;

void bucketSort (Point * points, STRCT_PARAM_NAME name) {
    switch (name) {
        case ENUM_X: printf("%lf\n", points->x); break;
        case ENUM_Y: printf("%lf\n", points->y); break;
        case ENUM_DIS: printf("%lf\n", points->dis); break;
        default: printf("Invalid\n"); break;
    }
}
```

Now, you can call `bucketSort` like this:

```
bucketSort(points_obj, ENUM_X);
```